# Fetch and display json data with javascript using reduce group sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, group-by, reduce

I have a multi array json data:

https://marialaustsen.com/foo.json

I need to return top 5 apdex by host, this format:
https://marialaustsen.com/grid-mode.jpg

So fare I have found top 5 apdex and sorted decending.
I think I will need to create a for each function and display apdex and name for each host. 
But I am not aware how to do this. Please see fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/marialaustsen/8uqafbs4/

```
fetch('https://marialaustsen.com/foo.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    appendData(data);
    console.log('data: ' + data);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('error: ' + err);
  });

Array.prototype.groupBy = function(prop) {
  return this.reduce(function(groups, item) {
    var val = item[prop]
    groups[val] = groups[val] || []
    groups[val].push(item)
    return groups
  }, {})
}


function appendData(data) {

  function getTopN(data, prop, n) {
    // dublicate array before sorting, to preserve the original array
    var clone = data.slice(0);
    // sort descending
    clone.sort(function(x, y) {
      if (x[prop] == y[prop]) return 0;
      else if (parseInt(x[prop]) < parseInt(y[prop])) return 1;
      else return -1;
    });
    // array.slice(start, end)
    return clone.slice(0, n);
  }

  // top 5 first instances of the descending sorted by apdex
  var n = 5;
  var topScorers = getTopN(data, "apdex", n);
  console.log("Top " + n + " apdex:");
  console.log('topScorers' + JSON.stringify(topScorers));

  topScorers.forEach(function(topScorers) {
    if (topScorers === 'host') {
      const groupedByHost = topScorers.groupBy('host')
      console.log('groupedByHost' + JSON.stringify(groupedByHost));


    }

  });
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the desired format?

Comment: Yes I have linked to an image with the desired format:
https://marialaustsen.com/grid-mode.jpg
Top 5 adex grouped by host.

Comment: What is top 5 apdex? Is that the items with the highest apdex? And each item has multiple hosts, how do you want them grouped by host? Do you want to make a group for each host, and then list all the items for that host?

Comment: Yes correct: top 5 apdex are the items with the highest apdex. Yes each item has multiple hosts, items (names) should be grouped for each host decending apdex

Answer (score 2):

if you have the data and want to render to the dom then do this

```
    var root = document.querySelector('#root');
    var a = data.map(item => {
        return ( 
            `<div>
            Name: ${item.name}
            <br />
            Contributors: ${item.contributors.map(cont => ` <span>${cont}</span>`)}
            <br />
            Host: ${item.host.map(ht => ` <span>${ht}</span>`)}
            <br />
            </div><br />`
        )
    });
    a = a.splice(',').join('');
    root.innerHTML += a;
```